# Print a diagram with html2Canvas, jsPdf, file-saver

Tags: svg, html2canvas, jsplumb, canvg

I have an Angular application where I use the jsPlumb library to create a diagram. The output of jsPlumb is a wrapper div with many other divs and svgs inside positioned as absolute.
This wrapper div I wish to print using libraries such as html2Canvas, jsPdf, file-saver, Canvg.
I use html2Canvas to convert the div into a canvas which I can then download and save with file-saver. The problem is that the produced canvas does not include the svgs, so part of the diagram is missing.
From what I've read I need to convert those svgs to canvas objects (before or after html2Canvas call, I do not know). Below is my effort, which basically ruins the output of html2Canvas

```
const diagram = this.diagram.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement;
    html2canvas(diagram, {
      width: 3000,
      height: 1000
    }).then((canvas) => {
      diagram.querySelectorAll('svg').forEach(async function (svg) {
        (
          await Canvg.from(
            canvas.getContext('2d'),
            new XMLSerializer()
              .serializeToString(svg)
              .replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '')
          )
        ).start();
      });
      document.body.append(canvas);
    });
```

Comment: Why convert the SVG to canvas at all? PDF, at its core, is also a vector grafics format.  Doing such a simple thing as printing a web page to pdf will show you the grafic is not converted to a raster format and retains scalability.

Comment: sorry, i don't quite understand, u're suggesting i simply print the page (with a print css file i guess) without doing any js processing?

Comment: Your question gives no hint as to your overall workflow or what you want to achieve, so all I could do was speculate.

Comment: i've edited the question to make it more understandable